# Removing multiple data entries based on a total number of entries per day

Tags: r

I start with a data frame titled 'dat' in R that looks like the following:

```
     datetime           lat       long      id extra    step
1   8/9/2014 13:00  31.34767    -81.39117   36  1   31.38946
2   8/9/2014 17:00  31.34767    -81.39150   36  1   11155.67502
3   8/9/2014 23:00  31.30683    -81.28433   36  1   206.33342
4   8/10/2014 5:00  31.30867    -81.28400   36  1   11152.88177
```

What I need to do is find out what days have less than 3 entries and remove all entries associated with those days from the original data.

I initially did this by the following:

```
library(plyr)
datetime<-dat$datetime
###strip the time down to only have the date no hh:mm:ss 
date<- strptime(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
### bind the date to the old data
dat2<-cbind(date, dat)
### count using just the date so you can ID which days have fewer than 3 points
datecount<- count(dat2, "date")
datecount<- subset(datecount, datecount$freq < 3)
```

This end up producing the following:

```
row.names   date    freq
1   49  2014-09-26  1
2   50  2014-09-27  2
3   135 2014-12-21  2
```

Which is great, but I cannot figure out how to remove the entries from these days with less than three entries from the original 'dat' because this is a compressed version of the original data frame.

So to try and deal with this I have come up with another way of looking at the problem. I will use the strptime and cbind from above:

```
datetime<-dat$datetime
###strip the time down to only have the date no hh:mm:ss 
date<- strptime(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
### bind the date to the old data
dat2<-cbind(date, dat)
```

And I will utilize the column titled "extra".  I would like to create a new column which is the result of summing the values in this "extra" column by the simplified strptime dates.  But find a way to apply this new value to all entries from that date, like the following:

```
    date        datetime         lat        long      id extra extra_sum
1   2014-08-09  8/9/2014 13:00  31.34767    -81.39117   36  1     3
2   2014-08-09  8/9/2014 17:00  31.34767    -81.39150   36  1     3
3   2014-08-09  8/9/2014 23:00  31.30683    -81.28433   36  1     3
4   2014-08-10  8/10/2014 5:00  31.30867    -81.28400   36  1     4
5   2014-08-10  8/10/2014 13:00 31.34533    -81.39317   36  1     4
6   2014-08-10  8/10/2014 17:00 31.34517    -81.39317   36  1     4
7   2014-08-10  8/10/2014 23:00 31.34483    -81.39283   36  1     4
8   2014-08-11  8/11/2014 5:00  31.30600    -81.28317   36  1     2
9   2014-08-11  8/11/2014 13:00 31.34433    -81.39300   36  1     2
```

The code that creates the "extra_sum" column is what I am struggling with.

After creating this I can simply subset my data to all entries that have a value >2.  Any help figuring out how to use my initial methodology or this new one to remove days with fewer than 3 entries from my initial data set would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plyr way.

```
library(plyr)
datetime <- dat$datetime
###strip the time down to only have the date no hh:mm:ss 
date <- strptime(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
### bind the date to the old data
dat2 <-cbind(date, dat)

dat3 <- ddply(dat2, .(date), function(df){
    if (nrow(df)>=3) {
        return(df)
    } else {
        return(NULL)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the data.table package

```
library(data.table)
dat<-data.table(dat)
dat$Date<-as.Date(as.character(dat$datetime), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
dat_sum<-dat[, .N, by = Date ]
dat_3plus<-dat_sum[N>=3]
dat<-dat[Date%in%dat_3plus$Date]
```